# Angular 2 multiple router outlets

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 application created with Angular cli, my app.component.html look like this :

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>

<app-top-navbar></app-top-navbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>

<app-right-sidebar></app-right-sidebar>
```

In my routes i have this condition that tells angular to redirect to /Login if no token is registered in localStorage :

```
canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) { 
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This works perfectlly, but my problem is that i would like to display the /Login (LoginComponent ) not is this router outlet with the sidebar, menu and footer, but in its own router-oulter without the other components.

Any idea on how to do it ?

Comment: my answer on this question could be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40260559/6942210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can have nested router outlets.

Here's my seed project that does just that.

https://github.com/danday74/angular2-coverage/tree/master/app

Comment: I can't understand how to link a componant to a other routes but the primary one !

Comment: look at my example, its just a basic seed project with minimal code

Comment: I need to conceptually understand it ! if you can juste explain me how to link a componant to another route it will be perfect ! thx

Comment: For a quick fix, just make sure your login route is tied to your login component and your login component has no router outlet.

Comment: It's my problem ! my login componant have no router outler but i  dont know how to tie login route to login componant. thx for you help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything in particular to hook up the login component to the default  except to make sure you have a route defined for the login component in your routing array. However if you want it to show in a certain area of the page, for instance, you may want to place it in a named outlet. To do that you would just specify the outlet in your routing component like this:

`{ path: 'login', component: myLoginComponent, outlet: 'leftSidebar', children: [] }`

The official docs have instructions on how to [set up the routing component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).